# NFA with half the strings in {0,1}^n

Tags: time-complexity, np

If there is an NFA M whose language L(M) is a subset of {0,1}* then how do you prove that determining if L(M) has fewer than half the strings in {0,1}^n for n>=0 is NP-hard.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decide whether the problem you are proposing is actually solvable.

Assuming that it is indeed solvable by an NFA, then it sure is solvable by a corresponding Turing Machine (TM).

> Let L(TM) = L(M)

Then, there exists a deterministic Turing Machine that can verify the solutions for the given set of problems. Hence, the problem is NP.

As per your question, in order to determine whether the  L(M) has fewer than half the strings in {0,1}^n for n>=0, the problem is decidable and can be reduced to P type.

Therefore, we can prove it to be NP-Hard by taking an algorithm that can change it to another problem that is already proved NP-Hard in polynomial time.

Required data missing to formulate the algorithm.